# Firefox blocks one tab from opening, but not another

Tags: javascript, firefox, popup

I've got an library, which provides methods for opening pop-up tabs (they interact with my app via window.postMessage api).

In first case, I've got Login button that triggers login service immediately:

```
loginButton.addEventListener(() => {
    myService.openLogin(); // everything works perfectly fine, new tab is opened
})
```

In second case, I've got a payment button, which delegates opening payment window after doing some checks

```
paymentButton.addEventListener(() => {
   dispatch({type: "todo"})
})

const myReducer = ... = {
   onTodo() {
      //perform a lot of checks
      myService.openPayment();
   }
}
```

What I described above is nutshell, in reality it takes a lot of functions and code, but in the end it calls service method. The time between click and `openPayment()` triggered is about 300ms.
I've heard that there's some kind of "click context" that is different in second case, so Firefox believes that my service is spam and blocks it.

Unfortunately I can't reproduce it and just hope someone have encountered such a problem

Comment: And yes, the problem is fixed by "Allow pop-up windows" in browser settings, but ```openLogin()``` works perfectly fine in both cases

Comment: Popup blockers allow windows to be opened synchronously in response to a click. But if you do it asynchronously, it's not recognized as being triggered by the click, so it's blocked.

Comment: Just Firefox? I'd expect all browsers to do this.

Comment: @Barmar yes, it's only Firefox, all other browser let it go. What about asynchrony - I was playing with setTimeout and other async stuff in ```openLogin()``` and it worked ok, browser let me delay execution for up to +-4000ms. IDK why second example is blocked

Comment: Rather than rely on the timeout after which the [transient user activation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Transient_activation) expires, can't you open the payment popup immediately, process the checks in that popup and navigate to the payment provider only if the checks were successful? If the checks fail, display the error in the popup.

Comment: @HeikoTheißen haven't heard of transient user activation , thank you in advance! Yes, that may be solution, but I still don't get why ```openPayment()``` is blocked, even though it's called 300ms after click, while ```openLogin()``` with timeout is called after 4000ms and still opens correctly

Answer (score 1):

The follow set-up allows you to experiment:

```js
function move(from, to, via, n) {
  if (n > 1)
    move(from, via, to, n - 1);
  to.unshift(from.shift());
  if (n > 1)
    move(via, to, from, n - 1);
}

function delay(n) {
  var a = [];
  for (var i = 0; i < n; i++) a.push(i);
  var b = [];
  var c = [];
  move(a, b, c, a.length);
  window.open("about:blank");
}
```

```html
Number N: <input id="N" type="number" value="1" />
<button onclick="setTimeout(() => window.open('about:blank'), 1000 * N.value)">Timeout N seconds</button>
<button onclick="fetch('http://httpbin.org/delay/' + N.value).then(() => window.open('about:blank'))">Request N
        seconds</button>
<button onclick="delay(Number(N.value))">Tower of Hanoi N levels</button>
```

(You cannot run this snippet embedded, because its sandboxed environment prevents opening popups completely.)

Google Chrome blocks popups that happen at least 5 seconds after the user activity, no matter whether the delay comes from a `setTimeout`, an HTTP request, or even synchronous activity like [Tower of Hanoi](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tower_of_Hanoi) with 28 levels (on my computer, your timing may vary).

From what you observed, other browsers may treat these kinds of delay differently.

Comment: Cool, I got it. But anyway, IDK why my second call is blocked...maybe FF somehow detects async calls and other stuff