How to open a URL in a new tab and redirect the current tab without triggering mobile browser popup blockers?
I'm working on a feature where I send a request to a server and receive a response. The response may or may not include a URL. If a URL is present in the response:

I need to open that URL in a new browser tab.
Simultaneously, I want to redirect the current tab to another page.

However, I'm facing issues with mobile browsers blocking the new tab because the window.open action doesn't occur as a direct result of the user's interaction (e.g., a click).
Additionally, opening a tab ahead of time (before the response is received) isn't an option. The request is triggered by a form button, which also switches steps in the form. Since the response may not always contain a URL, I can't open a new tab in advance for every button click.

Here’s what I’ve tried so far:

fetch('/api/some-endpoint')
  .then(response => response.json())
  .then(data => {
    if (data.url) {
      window.open(data.url, '_blank');
    }
    window.location.href = '/another-page';
  });


Expectation: Open the URL in a new tab and redirect the current tab.
Result: Works on desktop, but mobile browsers block the new tab.


Creating a link dynamically and emulating a click:

const link = document.createElement('a');
link.href = data.url;
link.target = '_blank';
link.click();


Expectation: Avoid triggering popup blockers.
Result: Did not work; the new tab is still blocked.

Is there a reliable way to achieve this functionality, especially on mobile browsers? Or any alternative approaches to handle this scenario?

Does this help? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77589766/firefox-blocks-one-tab-from-opening-but-not-another

The thing is that pop-up blockers job is to forbid the exact thing you want to do. That would be like asking "how can I open a pop-up without triggering pop-up blockers". If you find a way, that way will be forbidden in a future version of pop-up blockers.
